# java-ee - looping on servlet to avoid timeout

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-applications, jakarta-ee

i have some actions to perform in the server when the user choose which files he needs ( more than 3000 ) . but zipping them takes so much time that it takes more than 10 seconds and the servlet goes time out.

so what i want to do is to do it step by step without the interaction of the user such as i can call other servlet when a zip 50files per 50 files. 
the idea is to loop through the same servlet til the progression is 100%.

but when the client clicks on the button download 
i'm in the step 0%  and i zip 50 files but then 
 i forward to next jsp, lest say download.jsp with the webservlet download
**the objectif is to loop through this jsp/servlet again and again zipping 50 files every times til the zip is complete**.
but i don't know how do this without forcing the user to click on a form button so i can acces the doPost of my download servlet .

the objectif is when i forward to download.jsp to access automatically the DOPOST method of the doawnload servlet so it runs automatically .

thanks for your help!!